# Manipulating Xforms repeat collections. View and Model easily get out of sync

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

To recreate this problem, here is some sample code taken from Steve Pembertons Xforms for HTML authors tutorial.

After a few random clicks of the New and Delete buttons the UI will freeze and stop responding to further clicks because the model has gotten out of sync with the view (i.e they reflect differing number of instances of the repeating construct)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
<head>
 <title>To do</title>

 <style type="text/css">
   body { font-family: sans-serif}
   label { display: inline-block; width: 3em; margin: 0 1em }
          .xforms-repeat-item-selected { background: yellow}
 </style> 

 <xf:model>
     <xf:instance src="todo.xml"/>
  <xf:instance id="template">
   <items xmlns="">
    <todo><task/><status>unstarted</status><date/></todo>
   </items>
  </xf:instance>
     <xf:submission id="save" method="put" action="todo.xml" replace="none"/>
     <xf:bind nodeset="todo/date" type="xsd:date"/>
 </xf:model>
</head>
<body>
    <xf:group>
 <xf:repeat nodeset="todo" id="todo-repeat">
    <xf:input ref="date"><xf:label>Date</xf:label></xf:input>
    <xf:select1 ref="status" selection="open">
       <xf:label>Status</xf:label>
       <xf:item><xf:label>Not started</xf:label><xf:value>unstarted</xf:value></xf:item>
       <xf:item><xf:label>In Progress</xf:label><xf:value>started</xf:value></xf:item>
       <xf:item><xf:label>Done</xf:label><xf:value>finished</xf:value></xf:item>
    </xf:select1>
    <xf:input ref="task"><xf:label>Task</xf:label></xf:input>
    <xf:trigger>
       <xf:label>Delete</xf:label>
       <xf:delete ev:event="DOMActivate" nodeset="." at="1" />
    </xf:trigger>
 </xf:repeat>
    </xf:group>
    <xf:trigger>
       <xf:label>New</xf:label>
       <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
     <xf:insert context="/items" origin="instance('template')/todo" nodeset="todo" position="after" at="count(todo)"/>
     <xf:setvalue ref="todo[last()]/date" value="substring-before(now(), 'T')"/>
       </xf:action>
    </xf:trigger>
    <xf:submit submission="save"><xf:label>Save</xf:label></xf:submit>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been located: it is due to an event processing for an HTML object already deleted. Actually, deleting the last repeat item is enough to reproduce it. After that, even if XLSTForms engine is altered, some Javascript execution remains possible causing all the trouble...

Apparently, this happens only with recent Chrome releases and an exception in Javascript source appears in the console indicating that no element has been found for the event.

Ignoring those zombie events sounds great! This has been tested successfully with all recent browsers and it will be committed as soon as possible.

-Alain

Comment: Alain I don't think the syncing problem is restricted to Chrome and it is not just the use case where you delete the last repeat item (which has in fact worked for me on occasion). Am happy to wait and see what comes in the next release though.